# What's Property hits volume?

Tags: google-analytics

Property hits volume = pageview?

I checked my Google Analytics and yearsterday I got 200 users but when i go to **Administrator**->**Property**->**Property Configurations**->**Property hits volume**, I saw that i got 10,000 Property hits volume yearsterday.

Where is this traffic coming from?!

I want to know the meaning of "Property hits volume".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the definition from Google:

**Hit**

An interaction that results in data being sent to Analytics. Common hit types include page tracking hits, event tracking hits, and ecommerce hits.

Each time the tracking code is triggered by a user’s behavior (for example, user loads a page on a website or a screen in a mobile app), Analytics records that activity. Each interaction is packaged into a hit and sent to Google’s servers. Examples of hit types include:

- page tracking hits
- event tracking hits
- ecommerce tracking hits
- social interaction hits

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6086082?hl=en

Essentially combine your total number of non-unique pageviews and total number of non-unique event counts over the last 30 days, it should match closely (unless you have ecommerce and social as well)